# Tile mode in MapServer

Tags: google-maps, mapserver, tiles

I am trying to overlay the layers that are rendered using MapServer over Google maps.  I am pretty much new to this whole thing. So I tried to go through this example here http://mapserver.org/output/tile_mode.html.

Below is the code which I am using. Could someone let me know where I could be wrong or if there is any other way to configure this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html
   PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Google/MapServer Tile Example</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <!-- editing note this tag is incorrect here: <script> -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
     var urlTemplate = 'http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?';
        urlTemplate += 'map=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/xyz/map/map.map&';
        urlTemplate += 'layers=layer1 layer2&';
        urlTemplate += 'mode=tile&';
        urlTemplate += 'tilemode=gmap&';
        urlTemplate += 'tile={X}+{Y}+{Z}';
    var myLayer = new GTileLayer(null,0,18,{
                                 tileUrlTemplate:urlTemplate,
                                 isPng:true,
                                 opacity:1.0 });
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(35.35, -80.55), 15);
    map.addOverlay(new GTileLayerOverlay(myLayer));
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

OK, the main purpose here is that I already have a basic MapServer application. Now I want the to use the Google map street layers as the base map on top of which my MapServer layers would get rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never... I found this code [here](https://dosengis.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/create-mapserver-tile-image-for-google-map-api-v3/) for displaying mapserver tiles on v3 Google maps and thought id share it. You’ll need to replace `http://localhost/mapserver` with your local map URL (I’m using IIS).

I’m still having problems with the tile images not joining correctly but it seems to be an issue with mapserver not fully rendering the 256 tile, possibly projection in my map file. I’ll report back if I find a solution.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Overlay map types</title>
        <style>
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
          function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
            this.tileSize = tileSize;
          }

          CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
            var url = "http://localhost/mapserver?"; // change this line but keep the question mark
            url += "map=../maps/test.map&";
            url += "mode=tile&";
         // url += "layers=jalan&";
            url += "layers=layer1 layer2&";
            url += "tilemode=gmap&";
            url += "tile_metatile_level=1&";
            url += "tile=" + coord.x + " " + coord.y + " " + zoom;
            var myMapServerTile = ownerDocument.createElement('img');
            myMapServerTile.src= url;
            return myMapServerTile;
          };

          function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 10,
              center: {lat: 41.850, lng: -87.650}
            });

            map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(
                0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
          }
        </script>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR API KEY]&callback=initMap">
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```